# Find min/max values of $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3+3xy$ in the set $K=[0,4]\times[-4,0]$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find the biggest and the smallest values of the function $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3+3xy$ in the set $K=[0,4]\times[-4,0]$.
So using  partial derivatives we find that the critical points are $(0,0)$ and $(1,-1)$. After that we find that $(1,-1)$ is local minimum and $(0,0)$ is saddle point.
What generally is the procedure of finding the min and max values in the set $K$? As far as I know we should check for min/max values on the bounds of K. Does that mean that we should check the points $(0,0)$, $(0,-4)$, $(4,-4)$ and $(4,0)$ in this case, or what?

Comment: you need to check the behavior of $f$ on the boundary which is a square.

Comment: For a function of one variable over a closed interval, we check for extrema by finding critical points (with zero derivative) over the "interior" of the interval, then check the function value at each endpoint.  The analogue for a function of two variables is to find such critical points in the "interior" of the two-dimensional region, then check the (one-dimensional) "edges", then the (zero-dimensional) "vertices".  In general for any number of variables, we have to work our way down through progressively lower-dimensional parts of the region.

Comment: @Chilango i know that,the question is,should i just check the vertices of the figure to find is there min/max on its boundaries

Comment: Not only vertices of the square, but its sides, too.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak,could you tell me how that is going to happen?

Comment: I watched a lecture about the subject,where the "restriction" was circle,the lecturer said that in the square version we can use some sort of symetry.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write about the function
$$f(x,y)=x^3+y^3-3xy$$
for $x,y\in[0,4]$.

This is basically the same problem, it seems a bit more symmetric after the change of variables.

---

**Local extrema:**

You correctly found
\begin{align*}
f_x &= 3x^2-3y\\
f_y &=-3x+3y^2
\end{align*}
and identified critical points as $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

We can calculate also the second derivatives: $f_{xx}=6x$, $f_{xy}=-3$, $f_{xy}=6y$. We have
\begin{align*}
D_1&=6x\\
D_2&=\begin{vmatrix}6x&-3\\-3&6y\end{vmatrix}=36xy-9
\end{align*}

We see that for $x=y=1$ we get $D_1>0$ and $D_2>0$. So the corresponding matrix is
positive definite
and this is a
local minimum.

For $x=y=0$ we have $D_1=0$, so we cannot say from this whether it is maximum or minimum. But it is relatively easy to see that it is neither of them, since we can find close to $(0,0)$ points with positive values and points with negative values. (It suffices to check $f(\varepsilon,0)=\varepsilon^3$ for small $\varepsilon$.)

We can also ask Wolfram Alpha to check for [local extrema of x^3+y^3-3xy](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=local+extrema+of+x%5E3%2By%5E3-3xy+) to verify whether our calculations are correct.

---

**Extrema on $K$**

But we are interested in the extrema on the set $K$, not in the local extrema of the function $f$.

Since this set is closed and bounded and the function $f$ is continuous, it is guaranteed that the function $f$ attains maximum and minimum on $K$.

If the extrema are in the interior, then they are local extrema. So one candidate is $(1,1)$. We have $f(1,1)=-1$.

Now we check what happens on the boundary. We have $f(0,0)=0$, $f(4,0)=f(0,4)=4^3=64$ and $f(4,4)=4^3+4^3-3\cdot4^2=4^2(4+4-3)=80$.

What happens on the sides of the square?

- For $y=0$ we have $f(x,0)=x^3$. This function is clearly increasing for $x\in[0,4]$. So on this side we have minimum for $x=0$ and maximum for $x=4$.
- For $y=4$ we have $f(x,4)=x^3-12x+64$. We can check that this function is decreasing for $x\in[0,2]$ and increasing for $x\in[2,4]$. So the values interesting for us are $f(0,4)=64$, $f(2,4)=48$ and $f(4,4)=80$.
- The other two sides behave symetrically.

So we see that the values attained on the boundary are between $f(0,0)=0$ and $f(4,4)=80$.

The conclusion is that the maximum on $K$ is $f(4,4)=80$ and the minimum is $f(1,1)=-1$.

Again we can check WA: [extrema x^3+y^3-3xy for 0<=x<=4, 0<=y<=4](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=extrema+x%5E3%2By%5E3-3xy+for+0%3C%3Dx%3C%3D4%2C+0%3C%3Dy%3C%3D4).